# replace dot with comma in vba it doesnt work

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have currency sheet and after run my listing I have numbers like Euro currency 45018,0000 instead 4,5018  What is wrong?

```
Application.Workbooks("Zaliczenie.xlsm").Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("G3:H12").Replace What:=".", Replacement:=","
```

Comment: What happens when you set the format of the cells to *text*?

Comment: You need to format the underlying value of the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do that as below

```
Application.Workbooks("Zaliczenie.xlsm").Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("G3:H12").Replace What:=".", Replacement:="."
```

and now comma takes place instead of dot

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not exactly understand why you are replacing "." with ",", but if I'm right, you want to replace decimal points with ",". If so, the right way to do it is as follows:

```
    With Application
        .DecimalSeparator = ","
        .ThousandsSeparator = "."
        .UseSystemSeparators = False
    End With
```

By default, Excel uses system separators for displaying numbers (e.g., 4,5018.00). But after running the code in my answer, you tell the Excel that:

- do not use system separators (and use those that are defined by me, instead)
- set decimal separator = "," and
- set thousands separator = "."

for example, the number `4,5018.00` will be shown as `4.5018,00`.

Comment: Thanks @Saeed. I had datas from table online. It is reason. I was figuring out and  it was good point of view add false value.

Comment: Ok, I see. I hope I could have been help you solve your problem. Good luck!